# Reactjs: Replying comments not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Replying comments not working in reactjs.

Believe I have search through this venerable forum but most solution found could not resolve my issue.

This code works fine by displaying post and its corresponding comments from an array. Great Thanks to Stackoverflow Engineer **Ryan** for his help. Now I want to display each reply made on each comments as per code below

```
 {props.comment.replys.map((reply, i) => (<div>{reply.reply}</div>))}
```

but it shows error

```
Cannot read property 'replys' of undefined
    at Post
```

In angularjs I can just implement code below inside Post ng-repeat function.

```
<div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>

                <div>
                    {{ post.content }}
                </div>

                    <!-- Comments -->
                    <div ng-repeat='comment in post.comments'>
                        <div class='comment'>{{ comment.comment }} <b>{{ comment.id }}</b></div>

                    <div ng-repeat='reply in comment.replys'>
                        <div>{{ reply.reply }}</div></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Here is the updated code in reactjs**.

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
const Post = (props) => {

console.log(props.post);
console.log(props.comments);

return (<React.Fragment><li >
          {props.post.id} - {props.post.content}
        </li>
        <div>
        {props.post.comments.map((comment, i) => (<div>{comment.comment} --- {comment.id}</div>))}

    {props.comment.replys && props.comment.replys.map((reply, i) => (<div>{reply.reply}</div>))}   

 </div>

        </React.Fragment>
        );

};
class Comment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rec: [
{"id":"1","content":"first post","comments":[{"comid":"1","comment":"first comment","replys":[{"reply":"first comment reply1"},{"reply":"first comment second reply"}] }]},
{"id":"2","content":"second post","comments":[{"comid":"2","comment":"second comment", "replys":[{"reply":"second comment reply1"}] }]}
],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h3>Records</h3>
      <ul> 
        {this.state.rec.map((post, i) => ( 
        <Post post={post} key={i}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `props.comment` is what is undefined - add a console.log inside the render() function to see what props.comment actually is.

Comment: @Toby. the console.log says props.comment is undefine

Comment: So the answer lies in the component above this one, the one which passes `comment` as a prop. Are you giving this component a prop named "comment" ?

Comment: Sir Toby, please can you illustrate with sample. am just confuse on how to go about with it

Comment: I'd recommend reading through the (docs)[https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html] if you're hazy on the concept of passing props.

Comment: @jmarkatti can you please add sample json you get in props?

Comment: Sir Ma_dev_15. Post and comment are displaying correctly. if i want to show replies of each comment, that is where am having issues. if implement  {props.comment.replys && props.comment.replys.map((reply, i) => (<div>{reply.reply}</div>))}  , it shows error mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One comment on your second post in the sample data has no replies (replys) so it's quite expected that you see that error: you call `map` on `undefined`.

Try this instead (check if we have replies first and only map if some exist):

```
{props.comment.replys && props.comment.replys.map((reply, i) => (<div>{reply.reply}</div>))}
```

**Edit**

Here's one implementation of the `Post` method (I renamed it to `renderPosts`, you should do the same) that should work (better):

```
const renderPosts = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <li>
        {props.post.id} - {props.post.content}
      </li>
      <div>
        {props.post.comments.map((comment) => {
          return (
            <div key={comment.comid}>
              <div>{comment.comment} --- {comment.id}</div>
              {comment.replys && comment.replys.map((reply) => <div key={reply.reply}>{reply.reply}</div>)}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Note that I've:
- replaced the outer element with the shorter notation for fragments
- moved the iteration of the replies inside of the iteration of the comments (each comment has a list of replies)
- added the mandatory key attribute (you should add an id to the replies on your datamodel, I used the reply.reply value for the moment but that's in general a bad id, because there's no guarantee that all replies are different)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sir Andreas_D, I have implemented your solution and also ensure that all comments has a reply but am  still having the same error Cannot read property 'replys' of undefined
    at Post . I have updated the code with your solution and has also updated how i was able to achieve it in angularjs. it seems we have to pass reply inside props comment. Any further help from you sir will be appreciated. Between thanks for your help and time so far

Comment: Thanks so much at Sir Andreas_D.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Post = (props) => {
return (<React.Fragment>
        <li>
            {props.post.id} - {props.post.content}
        </li>
        <div>
            {props.post.comments.map((comment, i) => (
                <div key={"comment_" + comment.id}>
                    <div>{comment.comment} --- {comment.id}</div>
                    {comment.replys && comment.replys.map((reply, i) => (<div>{reply.reply}</div>))}// Here
                </div>
            ))}

        </div>

    </React.Fragment>
);
```

};

You can take replays data in this way.

Comment: Everytime we provide an array of jsx elements (like with mapping), we have to set the key attribute. I'd add that to the solution.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I edited my solition. @Andreas_D

Comment: Thanks so much at Sir SdkCy